# Rerun, recall main method/program

Tags: java

How do I rerun my program?

I have a class called `Class Game`
And in that I have a main method.
And a playagain class that looks like this:

```
    public void playAgain () {

    System.out.println("GAME OVER. Want to play again? (y/n)");
    String playagain = scan.nextLine();
    if (playagain.equals("y")) {
        // call the main method and rerun the program
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("OK, Goodbye");
        System.exit (0);
    }
}
```

How do i rerun and recall my main method? Simply creating a new object of the existing class does not work.

Comment: Have you taken a look into loops? (for loop, while loop etc) any basic Java tutorial would help.

Answer (score 1):

Java main method is `static` that means JVM can call it without creating any instance of class which contains main method. It is single entry point of your program you cannot recall main method from class

Instead put your code from the main method in another one and you call it as many time as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try a loop! Especially a while-loop could help!

Answer (score 0):

You need move your game implementation outside of `main` method something like this:

```
public class Game {

  public void playAgain () {
    System.out.println("GAME OVER. Want to play again? (y/n)");
    String playagain = scan.nextLine();
    while (playagain.equals("y")) {
      // just call the playGame again
      playGame();
      System.out.println("GAME OVER. Want to play again? (y/n)");
      playagain = scan.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("OK, Goodbye");
  }

  public void playGame() {
    // Move implementation from main method here instead.

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.playGame();
    game.playAgain();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it will help.

```
main (new String[] {})
```